# keep node_modules outside source tree in development (not production)

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, npm

I prefer to keep all generated files and dependencies *outside* my source tree while I work on it.

npm and grunt make that difficult:  npm will never allow moving local node_modules, so I have to use `--global` and `--prefix`.  But grunt does not support such a scheme, apparently.

How can I achieve my objective given the above constraints?

So, if I have a project:

```
foo/
    .git/
    src/
    gruntfile.js
    package.json
```

I want no extra files in my tree, specifically, `node_modules`. (Also `bower_components` and `build` etc but this is about npm.)  This directory should remain **untouched** while I am working on it and running it.  That is all.

Apparently `npm link` is supposed to do this, but when I tried it still installed all the dependencies in `./node_modules`.  Any other invocation I cannot fathom; the docs are not clear.

A related suggestion was to use another directory with symlink to my gruntfile or package.json, but grunt just resolved the symlink and continued to work in my original directory!

So far the closest I have come is to link to e.g. `~/.cache/foo/node_modules` from my project.  Although it achieves keeping the deps out of my tree, I still have this link cluttering my workspace.

I want to know if there is a better way.  Will some combination of `npm install`, `npm link`, `ln`, `~/.cache`, `NODE_PATH` and `PWD` allow me to run my project, from my source tree, and keep it clean of all non-source artefacts?

Comment: This would be pretty unusual; usually your gruntfile (and often also your node modules) would be in the source tree, to make working from different environments more consistent.

Comment: I am coming to see it is unusual, but I am having trouble understanding why.  I can understand the advantages of the node way of bundling dependencies, but fail to see why that deployment scheme should carry across into my development environment.

Comment: The reason is that it ensures that your users/developers can still use or build the software, even if a node module goes away or breaks needed functionality.

Comment: You seem to be answering a different question.

Comment: Well, to be clear, I'm not 100% sure how narrow your question is. You want node modules in the project directory structure for lots of reasons. Among other things, you may need different versions of the same tools to support different projects. This is not uncommon; it's actually a major reason that the norm is to put the files in the source tree, rather than doing global installs. To the extent you're also asking about committing the tools to source control, that's also a pretty common practice, to ensure the right versions of the tools are available with the project code that uses them.

Answer (score 6):

Swimming against standards is a Very Bad Idea ®.

What you **can** (and should) do is add `node_modules/` to your `.gitignore` (or whatever ignore file you have for your given source control system) so you don't *version* these files.

Also, you can use a directory like `src/` to organize your code and "shelter" it from the mandatory configuration files (`package.json`, `Gruntfile.coffee`, etc).

Comment: So the "standard" is to commingle source files and build artefacts?  Is this a "standard" based on reasoning or inertia?  Can you explain why it is a bad idea?  It seems to me a better idea to not have crap in my workspace and to centralise cachable artefacts somewhere else.  I have ~/.cache for this purpose.

Comment: @avdd You *don't* commingle them; you segregate them into appropriate directories. `/src` contains source, `/test` contains unit and other tests, `/build` (or similar) contains the build version, `/node_modules` contains node modules necessary to build and test, and so on. There are lots of theories on *exactly* how to do the organization, but there is widespread agreement that things like gruntfiles are not mere "build artifacts." If it's critical to your development process and "it" isn't the OS, it belongs somewhere in the same folder hierarchy as the rest of the project.

Comment: More evidence node people just don't get it I suppose.

Comment: Damn, I guess he put us all in our place.

Comment: I am not saying your intended organization is a bad idea, I'm just saying that **not following the standards** is a bad idea for obvious reasons: you may break code which assumes the existence of a standard folder structure. If the folder structure affects you so deeply, it is probably better to simply use a different technology. Golang has a approach more similar to what you describe.

Comment: The thing is npm (not node!) is the first tool I've encountered that flat out refuses to make this accommodation.  Perhaps you can suggest a different toolchain for front end development with some degree of feature/plugin parity?

Comment: Fortunately (unfortunately, for you), npm is currently the de facto package manager for everything javascript. Hey, just chill and accept the way of the `node_modules/`. I'm sure your 500GB HD has more than enough space for them :)

Comment: I don't think OP's intention is to swim against standards, but to follow a reasonably well-established best practice (out-of-tree builds).

Comment: Is there a reason NPM forces users to write to their hard drives over and over to avoid having node_modules versioned? When I build a project in some other language (e.g., Java), the Gradle/Maven repository isn't stored in the source tree, and my build system doesn't repeatedly copy 3rd party libraries into the source tree.